# "Send file by email" from Acrobat Reader does NOT invokes Items.ItemAdd() event for "Sent Items" folder?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have a VSTO addin with Outlook. I currently use the "Sent Items" Folder in my Items.ItemAdd() event to intercept the email to process and save it into a depository. Everything works Ok if I create new email and send from my Outlook, BUT if I open a local PDF document in Acrobat Reader and click on "Send file by email" toolbar button, use Outlook as default, it opens a new email, fill up the email address (to myself), the Items.ItemAdd() event is never called? I do see the email arrives in my "Sent Items" folder.

There is class MailItem which handle new email and has a Event_Send such as

> if ((m_MailItem is Outlook.MailItem)
> ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)m_MailItem).Send += new
> Outlook.ItemEvents_10_SendEventHandler(Event_Send);

When user clicks on Send button on the new email, the event Event_Send() is called which will call SubscribeSentFolder() in Addin class

> void Event_Send()
> {
> AddIn.SubscribeSentFolder(m_MailItem))
> }

These methods are in Addin class
private static Outlook.MAPIFolder m_sentFlder=null;
private static Outlook.Items sentitems=null;

```
public static bool SubscribeSentFolder(object Item) 
{ 
  m_sentFlder=((Outlook.MailItem)Item).SaveSentMessageFolder; 
  if (m_sentFlder != null) 
  { 
    sentitems=m_sentFlder.Items; 
    sentitems.ItemAdd += Items_ItemAdd; 
    return true; 
   } 
 } 

private static void Items_ItemAdd(object item) 
{ 
  object mapiOb=null; 
  if (item is Outlook.MailItem) 
  { 
    mapiOb=((Outlook.MailItem)Item).MAPIOBJECT; 
    if (mapiOb !=null) 
        Process(mapiOb); //Inside this Process method 
                         UnSubscribeSentFolder() will be called.
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that sets up the event handler and processes the event.

Comment: Sorry did not see your comment. Here is some code

Comment: I don't see any code. Can you edit your question and add code?

Comment: private static Outlook.MAPIFolder m_sentFlder=null;
private static Outlook.Items sentitems=null;
public static bool SubscribeSentFolder(object Item)
{       m_sentFlder=((Outlook.MailItem)Item).SaveSentMessageFolder;
 if (m_sentFlder != null)
 {
        sentitems=m_sentFlder.Items;
        sentitems.ItemAdd += Items_ItemAdd;
        return true;
 }
}
private static void Items_ItemAdd(object item)
{       object mapiOb=null;
 if (item is Outlook.MailItem)
 {
  mapiObject=((Outlook.MailItem)Item).MAPIOBJECT;
  if (mapiOb !=null)
   Process(mapiOb);
 }
}

Comment: Check if `SubscribeSentFolder` method actually runs. Other than that, it looks fine to me. Can you check that the event is fired in OutlookSpy (I am its author - https://www.dimastr.com/outspy): go to the Sent Items folder, click Folder button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, select the Items property, click Browse. In the Items window, go to the Events tab and look at the log at the bottom of the window as you send from Adobe Reader.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Yes, in the log I could see the correct "Sent Items" returns. I will check what you suggested in OutlookSpy.

Comment: Sorry. Something came up and need attention. With OutlookSpy running, it works! But if I turn it off, it stops working?

Comment: Does it work if you don't reset  m_sentFlder  / m_sentitems every time a message is sent?

Comment: We only reset the event, hence the m_sentFlder and sentitems, after it is done processing the email in the "Sent Items" folder when the Items_ItemAdd() event is invoked. It happens for the very first email and these m_sentFlder and sentitems are never reset because Items_ItemAdd() event is NOT invoked.

Comment: So SubscribeSentFolder() is called from the Items.ItemAdd event handler? How is it set the first time?

Comment: No. SubscribeSentFolder() is called from the Event_Send() which happens when user clicks on Send button of the email. And the UnSubscribeSentFolder() is called after the email has been processed in Items_ItemAdd() event.

Comment: Since Event_Send() works fine, it will call SubscribeSentFolder() the second time, right? And that would reset the m_sentFlder and  sentitems variables.

Comment: No. When user clicks on Send, the Event_Send() is called which will call SubscribeSentFolder() once.

Comment: Can you edit your post to add al the relevant code?

Comment: There is class MailItem which handle new email and has a Event_Send item such as
if ((m_MailItem is Outlook.MailItem)
 ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)m_MailItem).Send += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_SendEventHandler(Event_Send);

When user clicks on send button, it calls Event_Send() which in turn call SubscribeSentFolder() in Addin class
void Event_Send()
{   
 AddIn.SubscribeSentFolder(m_MailItem))
}

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko. I added snippet of code above. Do you want to me to add more code?

Comment: I edited your post above to include your code. I don't think it would even compile. Can you add more?

Comment: @Dmitry, I added some additional code info about my design in the original post. Just to state that it works OK when user creates a new email and send.

Comment: `MailItem.Send` event won't fire if the message was created using Simple MAPI or a mailto link. `Items.ItemAdd` event will still fire just fine on the Sent Items folder. Set up an event handler when your addin starts up, not when `MailItem.Send` event is firing.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Our plugin is designed to handle each new email whenever it is sent. In the log, I could see the MailItem.Send event is fired and the "Send Items" folder name is correctly registered in the SubscribeSentFolder() method. Everything seems normal except the Items.ItemAdd() is never fired??

Comment: I am 90% sure it is `MailItem.Send` event that is not firing. Where does the item come from?

Comment: We have a WrappedInspector class which will create MailItem every time a new email is created, such as   object mailitem = m_Inspector.CurrentItem;
                OpenMailItem openItem=null;
                if (mailitem != null)
                {
                    openItem = new OpenMailItem(mailitem);
                }..... I could see the MailItem.Send event is firing in the log as well as during debug, so I am sure it is firing.

Comment: `NewInspector` event won't fire in this case. Do tr to set up an event handler on the default Sent Items folder on Outlook startup.

Comment: In our Plugin, we have an option to process email only if user wants, so we only set up the event handler in this case on Sent Items if needed. I agree if Outlook is NOT running, then NewInspector event won't fire, BUT in our case, outlook is already running so I could see Send()/SubscribeSentFolder() is firing OK.

Comment: You are missing my point- NewInspector won't fire if you send from Adobe Acrobat Reader. You can see it (or rather not see it) in OutlookSpy: click Application, select Inspectors, click Browse, go to the Events tab, send a message from Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook may not wait until your mail is sent out actually when you sent items that way. It seems the mail item was put to the `Sent Items` folder after Outlook was closed or before your add-in subscribes to the event at the next startup.

A possible solution is to mark items put into the repository (it can be a user property or any other moniker) and scan the folder at each start for any unprocessed items. If you find any do the process for them.

For users with an Exchange Server account (non-Cached Exchange Mode or Cached Exchange Mode), the event will fire only for messages that are sent at the server after Outlook has started. The event will not fire for messages that are synchronized in Cached Exchange Mode immediately after Outlook starts, nor for messages that are already on the server when Outlook starts in non-Cached Exchange Mode.

Comment: Thanks Eugene for a quick reply. I have Outlook open when I do "Send file by email" from Acrobat Reader, I could see the message is sent and the "Sent Items" folder is added to my Items.ItemAdd() event (in the log I created).

Comment: Also when I read your comment "For users with an Exchange Server account, the event will fire only for messages that are sent at the server after Outlook has started.", I think if it is correct, then the event could NOT be fired because the email is NOT sent at the server?

Comment: The item is put in the Sent Items folder only after it is sent out.

Comment: Yes, I could see it in Sent Items folder after it is sent, BUT the issue is that the Items.ItemAdd() event is NOT called so I could not process it.